# How to use indexOf operation with the rss feed title

Tags: java

I have got 3000 symbols present in java array .

I am using ROME API to fetch the rss feeds ,
then i  am trying to check if the title contains anything part of array then only i must display the title

This is my program

```
String[] myFirstStringArray = new String[] {"ONE","TWO"}; // 3000 symbols 

try {
    String url = "http://www.rssmix.com/u/8159030/rss.xml";
    URL feedUrl = new URL(url);
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedUrl));
    for (SyndEntry entry : (List<SyndEntry>) feed.getEntries()) {
        JSONObject jsonobj_latestnews = new JSONObject();
        String title = entry.getTitle();
        jsonobj_latestnews.put("title", title)
        latestnews.put(jsonobj_latestnews);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Could you please tell me how to check

Comment: so you need to check if the title is present in the array?

Comment: i need to use indexOf operation  with the contents present in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the title is likely to be much less than the size of array.

```
String [] titleWords = title.split(" ");

ArrayList<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(myFirstStringArray);

for (String word : titleWords)
{
    if(wordList.contains(word))
    {
        /*do something here. you can get the index of the word by 
          wordList.indexOf(word); this index will the same as the index in myFirstStringArray*/
        break;
    }
}
```

this should do it

Comment: i need to use indexOf operation as anything related to it i must display

Comment: so lets say you get the title as "ONE" which happens to be at index 0 in the array. now what do you want to do with the index?

Comment: see for example i got the title from rss as "Google is number one search engine" as one is present in array i need to display

Comment: oh, so you need to check whether anything in your array, appears as a substring in your title

Comment: since the title coming in is non deterministic, i cant think of anything more efficient than a linear search. a small consolation could be that you can just end the iteration as soon as you get a match. or do you need to find all the matches?